# Kafka pods apparently going beyond their resource limits in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, strimzi

I am using kafka Strimzi operator. I have made  a deployment with resources request and limits as shown below.

```yaml
apiVersion: kafka.strimzi.io/v1beta2
kind: Kafka
metadata:
  name: kafka
  labels:
    app: strimzi
spec:
  kafka:
    version: 3.5.0
    replicas: 3
    listeners:
      - name: plain
        port: 9092
        type: internal
        tls: false
      - name: tls
        port: 9093
        type: internal
        tls: true
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 16Gi
        cpu: "8"
      limits:
        memory: 16Gi
        cpu: "8"
    readinessProbe:
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    livenessProbe:
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    config:
      offsets.topic.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.replication.factor: 3
      transaction.state.log.min.isr: 2
      default.replication.factor: 3
      min.insync.replicas: 2
      inter.broker.protocol.version: "3.4"
    storage:
        type: persistent-claim
        size: 80Gi
        deleteClaim: false
        class: longhorn
    metricsConfig:
      type: jmxPrometheusExporter
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: kafka-metrics
          key: kafka-metrics-config.yml
  zookeeper:
    replicas: 3
    readinessProbe:
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    livenessProbe:
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 5
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 4Gi
        cpu: "2"
      limits:
        memory: 4Gi
        cpu: "2"
    storage:
      type: persistent-claim
      size: 15Gi
      deleteClaim: false
      class: longhorn
    metricsConfig:
      type: jmxPrometheusExporter
      valueFrom:
        configMapKeyRef:
          name: kafka-metrics
          key: zookeeper-metrics-config.yml
  entityOperator:
    topicOperator: {}
    userOperator: {}
  kafkaExporter:
    topicRegex: ".*"
    groupRegex: ".*"
```

Having a look at prometheus/grafana, I am sseing the resource consumption limit per kafka pod is surpassed as shown in in the figures below

[image]

[image]

Can you please what i am misinterpreting/misunderstading? In fact, my understading is that the resource limit of a pod can not be surpassed in any way, and it will lead to throttling in case of CPU, and to an OOM for the memory case!!!

Comment: Strimzi does not do anything special. It just passes the resources you configured to Kubernetes. So I wonder if by making the question more generic you get a better chance for some response. It might be also worth sharing details about your environment such as Kube version, container runtime type, and version, etc. And also what kind of metrics are you showing in your screenshots, because there are many different metrics and without explaining what metric you are observing and where you get it, it might be impossible to comment on why it shows what it shows.

Comment: https://home.robusta.dev/blog/stop-using-cpu-limits

Comment: Expanding on @Jakub: Memory Usage != RAM Usage, at least not necessarily.

Comment: Check if the value is correct provided to Kubernetes. Use `kubectl describe kafka-kafka-1`.